# How do I populate a select tag with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to access a list of JSON objects (from mongo) in python to populate a dropdown list using flask templates.  Subsequently, I need to access the selected item.  I am having difficulty getting the list to populate.  Here's my python code and template.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I have not been able to find good documentation on how to populate the dd list with these templates.

PYTHON:

```
@app.route('/page', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def chooser():
    # Option list returns a list of JSON objects 
    option_list = get_options(g.user)
    # {u'_id': ObjectId('52a347343be0b32a070e5f4f'), u'optid': u'52a347343be0b32a070e5f4e'}

    # for debugging, checks out ok
    print option_list

    # Get selected id & return it
    if request.form['submit'] == 'Select':
            optid = o.optid
            resp = 'You chose: ', optid
            return Response(resp)

    return render_template('chooser.html')
```

HTML TEMPLATE:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Chooser<h2>
        <h3><table><form action="" method="POST">
          <td>
          <label>Select :</label>
            <select name="option" width="300px">
              {% for o in option_list %}
                <option name="{{ o.optid }}" SELECTED>{{ o.optid }}</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            <td>
              <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Select">
            </td>
              {% endfor %}
        </form></table><h3>

  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: The terminology here is a bit confusing. Technically, you are accessing JSON objects, but that is just part of the way that MongoDB transfers its data. The results are being serialized to Python dictionaries, and you are using the dictionaries. By saying you are using JSON objects you make it seem like you want to fill the `<select>` tag using Javascript (which actually does use JSON objects). Also, you are not accessing the list, you are trying to create it. I've changed the title to reflect this information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

First, when you call `render_template('chooser.html')`, you are never passing any arguments to the template rendering process. By default, Jinja2 does not error out if an attribute your reference is not found, so you get no error message. Basically, for the code in your template that looks like this:

```
{% for o in option_list %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

The innards of this for loop are never rendered because you never specify what `option_list` is. In this case, Jinja2 will just default it to an empty string, and then you are essentially looping over the characters of the empty string (which of course means the innards of the for-loop are never run).

So, you need to specify the template what the value of `option_list` is:

```
return render_template('chooser.html', option_list=option_list)
```

The other issue is that your HTML is going to be messed up due to where you've put your for loop:

```
<select name="option" width="300px">
{% for o in option_list %}
    <option value="{{ o.optid }}" SELECTED>{{ o.optid }}</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Select">
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I think you wanted to do the following:

```
<select name="option" width="300px">
{% for o in option_list %}
    <option value="{{ o.optid }}" SELECTED>{{ o.optid }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</td>
<td>
    <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Select">
</td>
```

See the [rendering part of the tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates), or the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Mark - that clarifies it for me.  It's so simple as I missed passing the list of objects in.  I don't know why I didn't see it before.  Can I make this +10?? ;-)