# Better solution to access individual list values

Tags: python, flask

I want to be able to access all values ​​in my list (There are about 70 values ​​in the list) so that I can place them anywhere on my website.
However, I find that my solution looks very ugly:

my df:

```
df=    
    A           B(m)         C(cm)      D(m)
    house        50           50        100
    bedroom      80           50        600
    bed          20           60        500 



   @app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def calculate():
    my_numbers = []
    my_column = []

    inpt = request.form['inpt']
    inpt2 = request.form['inpt2']
    output = False
     
    for text in df['A']:
        if text == inpt:
            give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
            give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis = 1)

    # Here we start to calculate with inpt2
    for column in give_text:
        column_edit = give_text[column]
        my_columns.append(column)
        column_edit = float(column_edit) * float(inpt2)
        
        if '(m)' in column:
            column_edit = column_edit + 'meter'
            my_numbers.append(column_edit)
        elif 'cm' in column:
            column_edit= column_edit + 'centimeter'
            my_numbers.append(column_edit)

    return render_template('calculate.html',my_numbers_0 = my_numbers[0], my_column_0 =
my_column[0], 
my_numbers_1 = my_numbers[1], my_column_1 = my_column[1], 
my_numbers_2 = my_numbers[2], my_column_2 = my_column[2], 
my_numbers_3 = my_numbers[3], my_column_3 = my_column[3], 
my_numbers_4 = my_numbers[4], my_column_4 = my_column[4], 
my_numbers_5 = my_numbers[5], my_column_5 = my_column[5], 
my_numbers_6 = my_numbers[6], my_column_6 = my_column[6], 
my_numbers_7 = my_numbers[7], my_column_7 = my_column[7], 
my_numbers_8 = my_numbers[8], my_column_8 = my_column[8], 
my_numbers_9 = my_numbers[9], my_column_9 = my_column[9], 
my_numbers_10 = my_numbers[10], my_column_10 = my_column[10], 
my_numbers_11 = my_numbers[11], my_column_11 = my_column[11], 
inpt=inpt)
```

and in my html it looks like this.. (I have shortened the list; these are not all values)

```
<p>{{ my_column_0 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_0 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_1 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_1 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_2 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_2 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_3 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_3 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_4 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_4 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_5 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_5 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_6 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_6 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_7 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_7 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_8 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_8 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_9 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_9 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_10 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_10 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_column_11 }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers_11 }}</p>
         ....
```

Is there a way to do it better?
I tried something like this here, but it didn't work:

```
return render_template('calculate.html',my_numbers = my_numbers, my_column =
my_column)
```

and in html:

```
<p>{{ my_column[1] }}</p>
<p>{{ my_numbers[1] }}</p>
```

Comment: What about using Jinja templating such as a `{% for i in mylist %}` loop to dynamically auto-populate each of the `<p>` tags, based on the contents of the list?  Then, only the list would be returned to the HTML template.  Something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476226/6340496).

Comment: `{% for i in my_column %}
<p> {{ i[10]}} </p>
 {% endfor %}`
If I try this, then 'Hello' ==> 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' and not what I want to achieve

Comment: In Jinja you can do this to iterate lists but not strings: `{% if var is iterable and var is not string %}`. Please use more meaningful names for your variables, this would make the code more clear. Also, you are sending variable names that don't seem to exist: my_numbers_0, my_column_0. What is the difference between inpt and inpt2 ? It's hard to distinguish variable names = lots of opportunity for bugs. This code is hard to follow.

Comment: I want to print every word from the list. But when I try in jinja, the individual letters are displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with easily with the simple but powerful jinja2 engine. Try something like this

```py
return render_template('calculate.html', items=zip(my_columns, my_numbers)
```

Then in the template

```html
{% for column, number in items %}
<p>{{ column }}</p><p>{{ number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, try to use *plural* where it makes sense, e.g. `my_columns` instead of `my_column` as there are several columns.

Comment: But how do I get every single column in my html so that I can use it individually?
`{{column [10]}}`, `{{column [12]}}` does not work

Comment: What do you mean with individually? Do you want to display a list and then item 10 and 12 again? What if there are <10 items in the list?